# Old scifi novel: alien king resurrected by humans who must then defeat him

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trying to identify an old scifi paper back novel. Basically an alien king is resurrected by humans after being found in a ship. After resurrection he gains power. In an attempt to defeat him humans go in search of his original planet; meeting an advanced race who build everything out of glass and think the humans are great because they use metal. The aliens have powers given to them by implanted growths, with names like doma-basa and tri-abasa.

Comment: When did you read it? And  check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Answer (score 9):

I have no personal knowledge of the book, but the terms  "dom-abasa" and "tri-abasa" appear in the book "[The Alien](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?537033)" by Raymond F. Jones.

[image]

You can read some of the book in the Google Books entry for "[The 11th Science Fiction Megapack](https://books.google.com/books?id=OSd6CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1520&lpg=PA1520&dq=tri-abasa&source=bl&ots=-E3PTBi8Cl&sig=nmQH9XD_0uBCyJIdMzE8Ym-HXhM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9u_6B8-jcAhVDMawKHXpRAO0Q6AEwC3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=tri-abasa&f=false)" which is where I found the terms.

Comment: Here is the back of the cover summary from [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Alien.html?id=AoFJDwAAQBAJ): Just speculate for a moment on the enormous challenge to archeology when interplanetary flight is possible ... and relics are found of a race extinct for half a million years! A race, incidentally, that was scientifically so far in advance of ours that they held the secret of the restoration of life! One member of that race can be brought back after 500,000 years of death....

Comment: Yeah, I think the "tri-abasa" sealed the deal, there can't be too many books with that in it.

Comment: That's quite a cover :D

Comment: Convenient nebula placement, eh @ChrisSunami?